# A shell script that never dies

Tags: linux, shell-script

I want to write a shell script that never dies 
i.e,
Shell script will repeatedly check whether Database is alive or not for every five seconds.
The problem is At times the shell script stops abnormally / killed by any one.

I want a script that will call itself even if it stopped / killed 
Is there any way to do that ???

Comment: I think you should use a supervisor mechanism to monitor your script (via another script or a Unix process) and check if the script died then rerun it!

Comment: @coffeMug using another script will again add overload to monitor that script . what do u mean by Unix process ?? i don't have idea about that ..

Comment: Power outage lengthy enough makes every script die at last. :-P

Comment: @Ram neither do I! :P I think you can also define a cron job to start the script in an interval if the script is died.

Comment: This might help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354019/monitor-a-process

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a crontab job to call your script.

```
crontab -e
```

Add the following line

```
* * * * * /path/to/your/script
```

This wil execute your script every minute. You can check here how to customize for other execution times. [Crontab man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab%205)

Sorry that I missed the requirement to run every 5 secs. But like Jonnhy mentioned in the comments, you can have the cronjob verifying if the script is running or not.

Script for crontab:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
ps -ef|grep -v grep |grep script_name
if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    path/to/script/script_name
fi
```

In your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
while true; do
    #perform the test        
    sleep 5
done
```

Or if you are using a linux that is still based on init scripts, you can perhaps a entry to /etc/inittab

```
10:35:respawn:/path/ro/your/script
```

Although I'm not really sure if it is a best practice to have this in inittab.

If your system is already with systemd, there is also a way to perform this, but I don't have experience with it to put it here.

Comment: +1 on this. There's no way to `trap` a `kill -9` so getting the script name out of the process table when its not needed is pretty much the only other way to minimize the risk that someone will ever try to kill it (which is what the OP is asking about).

Comment: Since he wants the script to run every 5 seconds, Cron won't run it often enough. But he could invoke the script every minute and have it check to see if it's already running and exit immediately if it is. That way the script would only be dead for at most a minute before cron starts it up again.

Comment: The crontab man page mentioned by @BitsOfNix lists the basic usage for the crontab command but the customizing options can be found by running `man 5 crontab` or by navigating [here](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a script with an endless loop, use a script that performs the task once but first sleeps for 5 seconds then calls itself in the background:

```
sleep 5
$0 &
# do whatever
```

That presumes the script is in $PATH, since it is invoked with just the name (`$0`).

If the script dies/is killed during "do whatever", the next iteration will still run.

Comment: If the "do whatever" task hangs, this runs the risk of running out of processes or memory on the machine. And if the script is killed while it's sleeping, it won't have a chance to invoke itself again so it will stop running.

Comment: @Johnny I completely agree; this is really a sketch of a tactic that could be used if there is a *specific* problem whereby the script is *dying* in "do whatever".  That's an assumption that includes the OP being a somewhat poor or lazy communicator, meaning, if this isn't applicable, s/he'll realize that, but if it is, s/he might not have thought about things this way and it is an option.

Answer (score 1):

If you have root privileges you can put your script into either /etc/inittab or /etc/init/script.conf depending on which your system uses.  Use the entries for /sbin/getty as an example of a process that is always restarted when it dies.

Comment: The inittab suggestion is a feasible one for SysV style systems that use it, but `/etc/init/script.conf` *is NOT* equivalent and will not work in the way you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the process isn't dying via SIGKILL, you can use `trap`, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap "" SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM

count=0
while ((1)); do
    echo $count
    sleep 2;
    count=$(($count+1));
done
```

You can't Ctrl-C (SIGTERM) that. If you want it to stop, you need to use `kill -9 [pid]`.

Comment: SIGQUIT (^\) could also be sent to terminate instead of using the shouldn't-be-used SIGKILL.

Comment: @Arcege Are you sure? Try it ;O

Comment: I didn't notice the bash shebang; I only use Bourne semantics myself and never noticed the difference with `trap` in Bash.